# Uploading files to an FTP server changes format of the file

Tags: ftp

I have some files I need to upload. When I upload them they look like this:

```
<div>
     <a href="#">X</a>
</div>
```

After I upload those to a FTP server they look like this:

```
<div>     <a href="#">X</a>     </div>
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix this?
Thanks!

( I know it doesn't matter for HTML, but the files include PHP and when you use comments in the file it will ignore almost everything in a file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original file is not using <'CRLF'> to denote the end of a line, try switching to binary mode before the upload (although it is still worth trying regardless in my opinion).

I do not have enough privileges to comment so I will ask here, what client are you using to connect to the server?

Comment: Thanks you very much, changing it from auto to binary worked ;) I don't really know what CRLF is. But I have nothing that tells that there is a new line ( like /n or so ). I am using FileZila 3.8.1.

Comment: Basically, in ASCII mode (auto), new lines are denoted by CRLF (carriage return line feed). If your file does not have this sequence in it, your file will not have new lines. In binary mode, you are sending the file "as is".